# BadImageFormatException in VS2013 Pro - no problems in VS2013 Web Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

Some time ago I created a WebAPI project using VS2013 Web Express. I could debug the project without any problems.  The app has been successfully deployed and it seems to work as expected.
I just installed VS2013 Pro and re-build the same project.  However, I can't debug it on my dev machine.  I keep getting BadImageFormatException error.  The app itself must be OK because it works fine if I deploy it to IIS.
I suspect that the failure is somehow related to IISExpress.  I can't figure out what is causing the VS2013 Pro debugger to fail while VS2013 Web Express works fine. Both of them use the same IISExpress config files - at least this is what I think.
If I go back to VS2013 Web Express then I have no issues with debugging.

Has anyone else run into the same problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember right, this is caused by attempting to run a 64-bit assembly in a 32-bit application pool.  You can change whether IISExpress runs in 32- or 64-bit mode using a registry key (from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rob/archive/2013/11/14/debugging-vs2013-websites-using-64-bit-iis-express.aspx):

> Command-Line:
>
> reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects /v Use64BitIISExpress /t REG_DWORD /d 1
>
> Regedit:
>
> 1.Navigate to:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\WebProjects
>
> 2.Make sure there is a REG_DWORD value named “Use64BitIISExpress”.  If not, create it.
>
> 3.Set its value from 1 (default = 0).